# Positive Lebesgue measure Poset - $\sigma$-linked

Tags: set-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $P$ be the partial ordering whose conditions are subsets of $(0,1)$ of positive Lebesgue measure, ordered by $\subseteq$.

> Show that P is $\sigma$-linked.

I need to prove that there exist a countable partition of $P$, such that any two set in the same piece of the partition are compatible, hence there exist $Z\subset (0,1)$ such that  $Z\subset A$ and $Z\subseteq B$.

**Attempt**
Using the Lebesgue Density Theorem, I know that any $A\in P$ will verify that $A\triangle \phi(A)$ is a null set. Where $\phi(A)$ is the set of points where $A$ has density 1, and $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference : $A\triangle B=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$.

I was thinking that I should be able to define an equivalence relation $A\sim B$ iif $A\triangle B$ is a nullset. Hence definition an equivalence class $[A]_\sim$. And inside each class I would have the desire property. But How do I prove that this partition is countable?

Comment: The partition you describe will not be countable. I recommend to work with an apropriate dense subset of the forcing you describe (as the $\sigma$-linkedness of a dense subset implies the $\sigma$-linkedness of the whole forcing), not because it is necessary, but conceputally easier. I do not think that the Lebesgue density theorem will be of great use here. Given two subsets $A, B$ of $(0, 1)$ of positive Lebesgue density, how  can you ensure that $A\cap B$ is still of positive measure? Try to work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any set $X$ of positive measure there is a basic open set $O$ so that $\frac{\mu(X \cap O)}{\mu(O)} >\frac{1}{2}$ (by the Lebesgue density theorem).

Consider for every basic open set $O$ the set of $X$ satisfying the above. What can you conclude about those?

Comment: I see that this give us a countable partition of $(0,1)$ because there exist a countable base for the real line (using open set with rationals end-points). However I'm failing at proving that any two elements of the set $\{X, \mu(X\cap O)>\mu(O)/2\}$ are compatible. I was trying to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are in this set, then maybe their intersection should, but I seem to be missing one argument

Comment: I think that any two such sets would intersect.

Comment: They would intersect and their intersection would have positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I just realized that the $\sigma$-linked condition requires only the elements to be compatibles, it does not require the common comparable element to be in the same partition. Thanks!