# Applications of Measure Theory in Set Theory

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Today my question is a bit generic. I'm interested in facts about set theory that need some kind of measure-theoretic knowledge to be proven, for example the covering theorem, the Radon-Nikodym theorem, the Lebesgue density theorem...

For example, I know that, if $\mathbb P$ is the poset of subsets of $(0,1)$ having positive Lebesgue measure, that is a partial order that is very useful in set theory to do forcing, then it is $\sigma$-linked. The only proof I know of this fact, that can be found here: [Positive Lebesgue measure Poset - $\sigma$-linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244349/positive-lebesgue-measure-poset-sigma-linked), uses deeply the Lebesgue density theorem.

I really like this result since I'm a set theorist that is also sometimes interested in analysis and measure theory, so I'm looking for more results of this kind to look at how deeply these subjects are connected.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: *how deeply these subjects are connected* --- Some mathematicians whose work might include what you're interested in: [Alexander Bezhanovich Kharazishvili](https://zbmath.org/?q=ia%3Akharazishvili.alexander-b) *AND* [Alexander Sotirios Kechris](https://zbmath.org/?q=ia%3Akechris.alexander-s) *AND* [Stevo Todorchevich](https://zbmath.org/?q=ia%3Atodorcevic.stevo-b) *AND* [David Heaver Fremlin](https://zbmath.org/?q=ia%3Afremlin.david-h) *AND* [Richard Daniel Mauldin](https://zbmath.org/?q=ia%3Amauldin.richard-daniel) *AND* [Arnold William Miller](https://zbmath.org/?q=ia%3Amiller.arnold-w).